# PHP Mailer If and Else

Tags: button, phpmailer

I am using PHP Mailer to send an email but I don't want it to send immediately. I want it to send after a button is pressed. So will PHP Mailer work If i try something like this...

```
<button onclick="button1">
Send the email
</button>
function button1 {
var x = 4
if (x == 4) {
//PHP Mailer...
```

Comment: Looks like you mix javascript and php. You can't. Javascript runs on the client side, there is no php there. Instead you have to post the message to the server, where a php script can then use that mailing class.

Comment: So is there a way to do something similar

Comment: Not much more I can say without you going more into detail. I _assume_ that you first have a form where a message is entered. That form is posted to the server. Now you want an additional confirmation to post the message? Then you have to first send out another form with the button and the message and send that back _again_ as a post, this time _with_ the button value. That way your server side can decide if the button has been pressed or not (yet).